# How to mount a file at startup?

Tags: mount

I've created a file and formated it.

```
# fallocate -l 1g /foo.img
# mkfs -t ext4 /foo.img
```

I can mount it using

```
# mount /foo.img /bar
```

But how can I make it permanent?

Comment: Stick it in `/etc/fstab`; you don't need the UUID bit, just specify the path directly.

Comment: Also may add Your mount command to /etc/crontab: @reboot root mount /foo.img /bar

Comment: Neither UUID nor path works. Every time I reboot my machine, I enter the emergency mode.